# Chrome: Stopping web workers when pausing in "main" thread

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the Chrome debugger, when you break in the main thread, all active web workers keep running and keep posting messages back to the main thread. Once you continue, it seems that the main thread works through all the received messages and works through them one by one.

The problem is that I have a web worker running that posts about 30 updates per second, so when I debug something for a while, what happens is that there's a multiple second freeze upon pressing play again.

Is there a way to stop all web workers when you debug something in chrome (besides pausing them manually every time)?

Comment: Might help, http://blog.chromium.org/2012/04/debugging-web-workers-with-chrome.html

Comment: Can you try adding a breakpoint in the worker?

Comment: @JuanMendes I can break in a worker, but why? What I want to do is break all workers when I break in the main thread.